# Facing issue while calling a stored procedure with if else condition in redshift

Tags: amazon-redshift

I created the stored procedure in redshift. Below is the code for that.

```
create or replace procedure sp4(f1 IN int)
as
$$
begin
    IF f1==0 then
        CREATE TABLE myetl(a int, b varchar);
    ELSE
        insert into new_tbl(id) values(47);
    END IF;
end;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

While calling the stored procedure I am getting the error like this

```
call sp4(0)
ERROR: operator does not exist: integer == integer Hint: No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You may need to add explicit type casts. Where: SQL statement "SELECT $1 ==0" PL/pgSQL function "sp4" line 2 at if
```

Answer (score 0):

Your comparison should be `IF f0 = 0 THEN`, with single equal signs. See the [Redshift PLpgSQL documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_PLpgSQL-statements.html#r_PLpgSQL-conditionals-if)